# Count only visible cells after filtering

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have been trying to do an excel formula but unable to find the right combination.

**Aim:** I want to COUNTIFS cells that are only visible after applying filters to the original dataset.

**Current/Wrong output: 38**

**Correct output: 15**

***Here is the current formula:***

```html
=COUNTIFS(INDEX('Current Month'!$A:AJ,0,MATCH("Dryness + Absorbency",'Current Month'!$A$1:$AJ$1,0)),"POSITIVE")
```

I have already tried the subtotal but the values are wrong. Secondly, the subtotal function displays error with index/match function.

**Here is what i tried:**

```html
=COUNTA(103,INDEX('Current Month'!$A:AJ,0,MATCH("Dryness + Absorbency",'Current Month'!$A$1:$AJ$1,0)),"POSITIVE")
```

I also tried replacing the **COUNTA** with **SUBTOTAL** but it shows error.

Hope someone could advice me on what syntax i can use to get the visible cells count and how i could incorporate it into my current formula. Thank you

Comment: There is a clever way of counting only visible rows here https://exceljet.net/formula/count-visible-rows-only-with-criteria

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. I will try using the formula provided in the link but it seems to be a little difficult with index match to be incorporated into the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is what you get if you substitute your index function into the standard formula that I mentioned

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX('Current month'!$A1:AJ10,0,MATCH("Dryness + Absorbency",'Current month'!$A$1:$AJ$1,0))=C10)*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(INDEX('Current month'!$A1:AJ10,1,MATCH("Dryness + Absorbency",'Current month'!$A$1:$AJ$1,0)),ROW(INDEX('Current month'!$A1:AJ10,0,MATCH("Dryness + Absorbency",'Current month'!$A$1:$AJ$1,0)))-MIN(ROW(INDEX('Current month'!$A1:AJ10,0,MATCH("Dryness + Absorbency",'Current month'!$A$1:$AJ$1,0)))),0))))
```

Yes it is a bit long but does work.

I have changed full-column references to first ten rows in order to test it. You can use full-column references but it is a bit slow

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX('Current month'!A:AJ,0,MATCH("Dryness + Absorbency",'Current month'!A1:AJ1,0))=C10)*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(INDEX('Current month'!A:AJ,1,MATCH("Dryness + Absorbency",'Current month'!A1:AJ1,0)),ROW(INDEX('Current month'!A:AJ,0,MATCH("Dryness + Absorbency",'Current month'!A1:AJ1,0)))-MIN(ROW(INDEX('Current month'!A:AJ,0,MATCH("Dryness + Absorbency",'Current month'!A1:AJ1)))),0))))
```

I had to change the row parameter in the INDEX statement following the OFFSET from 0 to 1 to get just a single cell reference to OFFSET from.

My test data looks like this and gives a count of 5 positives unfiltered, 2 positives when filtered for an 'x' in column E.

[image]

Comment: Hi Tom Sharpe, 
   
    The solution is great, but i would like to add one more condition where column c is pampers. Is it possible to add one more condition into the formula? I tried but i keep having error, maybe it could be due to the placement.

Comment: Sorry I haven't come back to you - I think I've got this set up on my computer at home so will try it later

Comment: It should be just =SUMPRODUCT(('Current month'!C:C="Pampers")*INDEX... and the rest of the formula the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use the subtotal function. It will adjust the return value based on filters.

More info here on how to make it conditional: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/63754-subtotal-if.html

Comment: Hi, i have already tried the subtotal but it doesnt work. It shows error.